# psql adding blank spaces to a text

Tags: psql

Hi I'm new to psql and I have the problem that I have a VARCHAR as variable in a function and I want to add blank spaces before and after it. Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(word VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
$word2$
DECLARE
word    VARCHAR;
word2   VARCHAR;
BEGIN
word2 = ' ' word ' ' ;
RETURN word2;
END;
$word2$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Is there a quick and easy way?
Thanks.

Comment: You can concatenate strings with  the `||` operator:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0):

you declare:

```
word    VARCHAR;
```

and yet you have IN argument with same name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(word VARCHAR)
```

What happens is: function ignores argument word, because you redeclare it. From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-declarations.html):

> If the DEFAULT clause is not given then the variable is initialized to
>   the SQL null value

You don't have `:= 'come value'` after `word    VARCHAR` so it becomes null.

On the other hand concatenation operator  `||` does not ignore `NULL` as `concat()` function, so the result of `' ' word ' '` always be `NULL`, no matter what.

Here is example of working function:

```
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(word VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
$word2$
BEGIN
  RETURN ' '||word||' ';
END;
$word2$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 13.018 ms
t=# select func('text');
  func
--------
  text
(1 row)

Time: 0.260 ms
```